# ¿Por qué sólo toma el primer Registro JS?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Actualmente tengo esta tabla, que la lleno con foreach:

```
    <div class="card" id="accordionDatosGenerales">
    <h5 class="card-header" id="headingOne" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne" style="background: #006AA6 !important; color: #fff !important;">
        Información General
    </h5>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionDatosGenerales">
        <div class="card-body">
            @foreach (var a in Model.datosSolicitantes)
            {
                <div class="line-content">
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <input type="hidden" id="Solicitud" value="@Model.IdExpediente" />
                        <input type="text" id="IdSolicitante" value="@a.IdSolicitante" />
                        <table class="table table-borderless table-sm" id="tabla">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <th style="width: 16%;">Número Solicitud Presto</th>
                                    <td style="width: 18%;">@Model.IdExpediente</td>
                                    <th style="width: 14%;">Numero de Solicitud</th>
                                    <td style="width: 16%;">@Model.NumeroSolicitud</td>
                                    <th style="width: 16%;">Fecha Solicitud</th>
                                    <td style="width: 16%;">@Model.FechaSolicitud</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Producto</th>
                                    <td>@Model.Producto</td>
                                    <th>Sub Producto</th>
                                    <td>@Model.SubProducto</td>
                                    <th>Sistema Amortización</th>
                                    <td>@Model.SistemaAmortizacion</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Tipo de Documento</th>
                                    <td>
                                        @a.TipoDocumento
                                    </td>


                                    <th>Numero de Documento</th>
                                    <td>@a.NumeroDocumento</td>
                                    <th>Nombre Cliente</th>
                                    <td>@a.NombreCliente</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Numero Tel. Movil</th>
                                    <td>@a.NumeroCelular</td>
                                    <th>Numero Tel. Residencia</th>
                                    <td>@a.NumeroTelefono</td>
                                    <th>Email</th>
                                    <td>@a.Email</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Tipo de Solicitante</th>
                                    <td>@a.TipoSolicitante</td>
                                    <th>Fecha de Nacimiento</th>
                                    <td>@a.FechaNacimiento</td>
                                    <th>Estado Civil</th>
                                    <td>@a.EstadoCivil</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Direccion Residencia</th>
                                    <td>@a.Direccion</td>
                                    <th>Ciudad Residencia</th>
                                    <td>@a.Ciudad</td>
                                    <th>Pais Residencia</th>
                                    <td>@a.Pais</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Empleado Banco</th>
                                    <td>@a.EmpleadoBanco</td>
                                    <th>VIP / Banca Preferente</th>
                                    <td>@a.VIP</td>
                                    <th>PEP</th>
                                    <td>@a.PEP</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <hr />
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <hr />
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <hr />
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <hr />
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <hr />
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <hr />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Gestor Comercial</th>
                                    <td>@Model.GestorComercial</td>
                                    <th>Email Gestor Comercial</th>
                                    <td>@Model.EmailGestorComercial</td>
                                    <th>Canal de Venta</th>
                                    <td>@Model.CanalVenta</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Oficina</th>
                                    <td>@Model.Oficina</td>
                                    <th>Region</th>
                                    <td>@Model.Region</td>
                                    <th>Ciudad Oficina</th>
                                    <td>@Model.CiudadOficina</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <hr />
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <hr />
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <hr />
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <hr />
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <hr />
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <hr />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Monto Aprobado</th>
                                    <td>@Model.MontoAprobado</td>
                                    <th>Plazo Aprobado</th>
                                    <td>@Model.PlazoAprobado</td>
                                    <th>Fecha Aprobación</th>
                                    <td>@Model.FechaAprobacion</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Porcentaje LTV Aprobado</th>
                                    <td>@Model.PorcentajeLTVAprobado</td>
                                    <th>Es Feria Hipotecaria</th>
                                    <td>@Model.EsFeriaHipotecaria</td>
                                    <th>Credito en el Exterior</th>
                                    <td>@Model.CreditoExterior</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <hr />
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <hr />
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <hr />
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <hr />
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <hr />
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <hr />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Destino Inmueble</th>
                                    <td>@Model.DestinoInmueble</td>
                                    <th>Fecha Entrega Inmueble</th>
                                    <td>@Model.FechaEntregaInmueble</td>
                                    <th>Fecha Firma Escritura</th>
                                    <td>@Model.FechaFirmaEscritura</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Constructora</th>
                                    <td>@Model.Constructora</td>
                                    <th>Proyecto</th>
                                    <td>@Model.Proyecto</td>
                                    <th>VIS</th>
                                    <td>@Model.VIS</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
            <ul id="pagin"></ul>
            <button type="button" id="btnEditar" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Editar Solicitante</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Esto funciona correctamente, pero tengo un problema al intentar cargar la información del registro ya que cuando tengo mas de dos registros siempre me toma el IdSolicitante del primer registro, así tengo actualmente el JS que toma los valores de los input.

```js
$("#btnEditar").click(function () {
        var obj = {};
        obj = {
            IdExpediente: $("#Solicitud").val(),
            IdUsuario: $("#IdSolicitante").val(),
        };
        console.log(obj);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Obtenrda",
            data: JSON.stringify(obj),
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) {
                $.each(result, function (i, v) {
                    console.log(result);
                    $('#NumeroSolicitud').val(v.NumeroSolicitud);
                    $('#Producto').val(v.IdProducto);
                    $('#SistemaAmortizacion').val(v.SistemaAmortizacion);
                    $('#DestinoInmueble').val(v.DestinoInmueble);
                    $('#FechaEntregaInmueble').val(v.FechaEntregaInmueble);
                    $('#Constructora').val(v.Constructora);
                    $('#Proyecto').val(v.Proyecto);
                    $('#TipoDocumento').val(v.IdDocumentoIdentificativo);
                    $('#NumeroDocumento').val(v.NumeroIdentificacion);
                    $('#Nombre').val(v.Nombre);
                    $('#PrimerApellido').val(v.PrimerApellido);
                    $('#SegundoApellido').val(v.SegundoApellido);
                    $('#codOficiSegundoApellidona').val(v.SegundoApellido);
                    $('#NumeroCelular').val(v.TelefonoCelular);
                    $('#NumeroTelefono').val(v.NumeroTelefonoResidencia);
                    $('#Email').val(v.Email);
                    $('#TipoRelacionCredito').val(v.IdTipoRelacionCredito);
                    $('#FechaNacimiento').val(v.FechaNacimiento);
                    $('#FechaFirmaEscritura').val(v.FechaFirmaEscritura);
                    $('#EstadoCivil').val(v.IdEstadoCivil);
                    $('#Direccion').val(v.DireccionResidencia);
                    $('#Ciudad').val(v.IdCiudadResidencia);
                    $('#EmpleadoBanco').val(v.EmpleadoBanco);
                    $('#VIP').val(v.VIP);
                    $('#PEP').val(v.PEP);
                });
                $("#FechaNacimiento").datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "dd-mm-yy");
                $("#FechaEntregaInmueble").datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "dd-mm-yy");
            },
            error: function (errormessage) {
                console.log(errormessage.responseText);
            }
        });
    });
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que me tome el IdSolicitante correcto por cada registro?
Estoy trabajancon Asp.Net MVC5
¿Cómo podría generar un id autoincremetal? ya que no tengo idea de como hacerlo
¿Cómo podría tomar la posición con jquery?

Comment: Bienvenido a stackoverflow en español. Te recomiendo que, antes de formular una pregunta, visites el Centro de Ayuda. Allí podrás aprender como formular una buena pregunta. Para empezar podrías colgar el código en texto y no como imagen, gracias.

Comment: Por favor, No utilices imágenes para el código. copia y "pega" el código directamente en la Pregunta. Y otra cosa, utilizas ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: Estas haciendo un foreach y generando elementos que tienen el mismo id. Dos elementos no deberían tener el mismo id. Genera esos id's para que se llamen IdSolicitante0, IdSolicitante1, etc, asi después podrás sacar el valor con jquery con $("#IdSolicitante" + posicion).val()

Comment: Solamente es 1 botón editar para todas las tablas que te genera dinamicamente?

Comment: Si solamente es un boton

Comment: Podrías hacer un botón por tabla dinámica, a ese botón le agregas el idSolicitante en una propiedad data() y ya en el evento clic tomas ese id que tiene el botón y lo mandas en el ajax. Ademas te recomiento que uses clases en lugar de repetir el idSolicitante en todos tus inputs dinamicos.